# How do match a list of my base files to their corresponding matching 'phenotype' files

Tags: r, linux, bash, while-loop

I am trying to run a script that matches a list of 99 base files containing genetic data to their corresponding 99 phenotype files. Each base file has 1 match, and I only want to run the 1 base file to its corresponding exact match. I am very new to programming, this task might seem very easy but I am having a hard time with it. As of right now, I have taken a 'caveman' approach. I have deconstructed my table with all my phenotype files into 99 separate files named after the phenotype. I then created a list with 2 columns, column 1 contains all the names of the base files matched with a column with the names of the phenotype files. This works, but I want to improve the script and make it more efficient, your help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a Bash script

```
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -t 01:59:00
```

Here I load the appropriate modules

```
module load 2020
module load R/3.3.1-intel-2016b
```

Here I set my variables and make sure my programme has access to the files it needs

```
cd /nfs/home3/vanderes/Donders/Desikan_Killian/ 

file_name=$1 
pheno_name=$2

PRSICEPATH=/home/vanderes/R/PRSice.R 
 
GENTYPE=/home/vanderes/Donders/Emma2Yingjie/adh_amd1_eur_es-postpc2.hg19.ch.fl.bgn

COVS=/home/vanderes/Donders/Emma2Yingjie/Mcovall_4prsice.txt  

PRSICE_linux=/home/vanderes/R/PRSice_linux
```

Here I make a while loop to feed my list of file names to the programme

```
while read file_name pheno_name 
do 
#pheno-col does not work, maybe i have to make seperate phenotype files after all fuck. 
Rscript $PRSICEPATH  --dir . --prsice $PRSICE_linux  --no-default \
 --base ${file_name}  --stat 5 --beta  --A1 3 --A2 4 --chr 0 --snp 1 --bp 2 --pvalue 8 --index \
 --target $GENTYPE  --pheno-file ${pheno_name} --ignore-fid  --cov-file $COVS --cov-factor Batch Site Sex \
  --missing SET_ZERO --bar-levels 0.0000005,0.0000005,0.000005,0.00005,0.0005,0.001,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1 \
  --missing SET_ZERO  --thread 1 --quantile 100 --quant-break 1,5,10,20,40,60,80,90,95,99,100 --quant-ref 60 --out ${pheno_name}   

done < file_list.txt
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with an example of the filenames? I'd suggest using `list.files` along with its `pattern` argument.

Comment: An example of the file_list and its first and second column: 
```ready_0189.txt.gz      lh_cortex.txt
    ready_0191.txt.gz      left_lateral_Ventricle.txt```

Comment: So there is no logical pattern that allows you to match the files?

Comment: No, as of right now there is not!

Comment: Are the file creation timestamps ordered according to your needs?

Comment: Yes, both the input files are ordered in required creation timestamps